# Permission error using kubectl after GKE Kubernetes cluster migration from one organization to another

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

I had a GKE cluster my-cluster created in a project that belonged to organization org1.

When the cluster was created I logged in with user@org1.com using `gcloud auth login` and configured the local kubeconfig using `gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster --region europe-west4 --project project`.

Recently we had to migrate this project (with the GKE cluster) to another organization, org2. We did it sucessfully [following the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration).

The IAM owner in org2 is user@org2.com. In order to reconfigure the kube config I followed the previous steps, logging in in this case with user@org2.com:

`gcloud auth login`

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster --region europe-west4 --project project`.

When I execute `kubectl get pods` I get an error referencing the old org1 user:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "user@org1.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default": requires one of ["container.pods.list"] permission(s).
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be *the* answer but hopefully it's part of the answer.

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials` is a convenience function that mutates the local `${KUBECONFIG}` (often `~/.kube/config`) and populates it with `cluster`, `context` and `user` properties.

I suspect (!?), your `KUBECONFIG` has become *inconsistent*.

You should be able to edit it directly to better understand what's happening.

There are 3 primary blocks `clusters`, `contexts` and `users`. You're looking to find entries (one each `cluster`, `context`, `user`) for your old GKE cluster **and** for your new GKE cluster.

**Don't delete anything**

Either back the file up first, or re`name` the entries.

Each section will have a `name` property that reflects the GKE cluster name `gke_${PROJECT}_${LOCATION}_${CLUSTER}`

It may be simply that the `current-context` is incorrect.

> **NOTE** Even though `gcloud` creates `user` entries for each cluster, these are usually identical (per user) and so you can simplify this section.

> **NOTE** If you always use `gcloud`, it does a decent job of tidying up (removing entries) too.

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted DazWilking's answer since in a way he was right, the config file was "inconsistent".

The problematic bit was in the user section:

```
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: xxxxxx      
        expiry: "2021-07-11T18:36:42Z"
```

For some reason when using the `gcloud container clusters get-credential` command it created all items (cluster, context and user)  with an invalid user section.

To fix it I connected to a cloud shell directly from the Google Cloud web console and checked the `./kube/config` file there. My local config was missing the cmd-path, cmd-args, expiry-key and token-key entries:

```
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: xxx
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: /Users/xxx/applications/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2021-07-11T18:36:42Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
```